# Jw_player: Error loading player: No playable sources found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jwplayer

I am using jw player to play videos in my rails application. but its giving no playable source found error. Please help me to solve this error.

my code:

```
 <div id="mediaplayer">
 </div>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= asset_path('jwplayer.js') %>" ></script>
 <script>jwplayer.key="key_info_here=="</script> 

 <script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
 jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
'id': 'mediaplayer',
'width': '480',
'height': '270',
'file': "http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.mp4",
'type' : 'video',
'streching' : 'uniform',
'smoothing' : 'true',
'controlbar.position' : 'bottom',
'primary': 'flash',
'flashplayer': "<%=escape_javascript(asset_path('flash.swf')) -%>",
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried in different browser..?\

Comment: ok..this looks fine, have you included jw_player helper gem..?

Comment: ok then i will check that in my code and get back to you if i will get any solution

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you are running this?

Comment: did you get the solution of this post.

Comment: yes. i got the solution

Comment: Hello, if you've solved this question, then you should consider giving back by posting an answer to your own question below.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the above problem as follows..

```
 <div id="mediaplayer" align="center">
 </div>    

 <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="wjl6yMFUQPDPAec4DULRmMulzyO8Q9omr+k6Fw==";</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
   flashplayer: "<%#= asset_path('player.swf') %>",
   image: "http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.jpg",
   file: "http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.mp4",
   height: 270,
   width:480
 });
```